# Dropdownlist Datasource and adding extra item from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, drop-down-menu, .net-4.0

I have a `DropDownList` that is associated with a `DataSource` in the aspx page. I need to add one more item when the page is loaded.

My Code:

```
<asp:LabelDropDownList ID="ddlVisualTemplate" runat="server" LabelText="Visual Template:"      DataSourceID="VisualTemplateDataSource" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlVisualTemplate_SelectedIndexChanged"/>                         

<asp:EntityDataSource ID="VisualTemplateDataSource" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="name=Entities" 
     DefaultContainerName="Entities" EnableFlattening="False" 
     EntitySetName="tbEmailVisualTemplates">
```

And I am trying to an extra item to it:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ddlVisualTemplate.Items.Add(new ListItem("None", string.Empty));
        }
    }
```

If I debug the code, it goes through it. But When the page is displayed dropdown doesn't contain `"None"`.

Comment: You should do that, but after te data is rendered, on the DataBound Event

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's most probably because you're adding the item before the `DataBind()`. If you want to add an item with

```
ddlVisualTemplate.Items.Add()
```

then you have to do it **after** the dropdown is being bound.

If you look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx then DataBind is being done in PreRenderComplete. So you have to add the element in some event that occurs after PreRenderComplete.
Or you could do it on the `ddlVisualTemplate.DataBound` event.

Answer (score 15):

Probably too late for the original poster, but maybe useful for other users:

You can add the value "None", "Choose value", etc. in the designer (or in the code) and prevent `DataBind` from overwriting it, by setting `AppendDataBoundItems="true"`. This will make `DataBind` append rather than clear.

Below example from Scott Guthrie's post [ListControl.AppendDataBoundItems Property in ASP.NET 2.0](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/29/436804.aspx).

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="state" DataValueField="state">    
    <asp:ListItem Text="(Select a State)" Value="" />   
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
                   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:pubsConnectionString %>"
                   SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [state] FROM [authors]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 6):

You could easily fix this by setting the datasource prgrammatically:

```
ddlVisualTemplate.DataSource = VisualTemplateDataSource;
ddlVisualTemplate.DataBind();

ddlVisualTemplate.Items.Add(new ListItem("None", string.Empty));
```

BTW, these datasource controls are a wrong thing in asp.net in my opinion. I don't like the idea of defining the data source and giving the control over db connections to the aspx page. For a better way of doing this just google about session per request pattern, separation of concerns and n-tier apps.

Update: instead of "VisualTemplateDataSource" you could call directly the data. I don't know EF, but it might be like this: "DataContext.tbEmailVisualTemplates". You have to set your datacontext. And then you can get rid of the datasource control.

Answer (score 2):

Use this to add an item in the bound dropdown list at 0 index

```
ddlTicketType.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All", "0"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me but it puts the value in the end.

```
protected void ddlTest_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ddlTest.Items.Add(new ListItem("All", string.Empty));
    }
}
```

Comment: ddlTest.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All", string.Empty));
Will put the item at the top