# "property value is not valid" error when adding event to a control in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, drop-down-menu

Detail error message is: `Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.`

I opened my project after a couple of weeks and now I get his error. What I am trying to do is add extra entry to a Dropdownlist which is already bound to SQLDataSource, similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541645/dropdownlist-datasource-and-adding-extra-item-from-c). Also there is a  question on [windows form question](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/573959/problem-creating-onclick-event-of-a-imagebutton). Is there any solution to this?

**Edit:** Looks like the problem line is the top line in .aspx file. This line is underlined (zigzag) and says "Syntax Error". This is causing code break in .aspx.cs file.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ContactIDs.aspx.cs" Inherits="ContactIDs" %>
```

Comment: So what is this, ASP.NET or Winforms(with Webbrowser component)? Why is the firstl link(manually adding extra items) related to your issue? Maybe following helps: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vseditor/thread/d4e2df71-6f3d-4081-92c2-4938fd3e648a/

Comment: This is .aspx page. What I found is the code setting somehow changed from C# to VB.NET automatically and therefor all properties values became invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own answer: Apparently there was no error in the code but it somehow code corrupt, may be its setting.

Fix: Create a new .aspx file (webform), copy the contents of both .aspx and .aspx.cs file in the new files. The error is resolved. Make sure to check c# in language setting when creating new file.